# can the to-path in pgf/tikz circuits be used to name a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to define a few components for my circuits library to use with the `circuit.ee` library, and I have a couple of questions:

1. Does the to-path create a node on its path or just a complex path i.e. in

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
   \draw (0,0) to[resistor] (3,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

   is the resistor a node?
2. If it is indeed a node (which I think it is since I can create anchors for it) is it possible to name the node and subsequently access its anchors?
   I have tried the following that does not work

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
   \draw (0,0) to[resistor, name=res] (3,0);
   \draw (0,2) -- (res.north);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   ```

   and a bunch of other things that didn't work.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the option sent to the `resistor` node itself by using the following:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw (0,0) to[resistor={name=s}] (3,0);
\node[below,align=center]  at (s.south) {Resistance \\is futile};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus, you can refer to that node later with the name you give.

Comment: That didn't only solve my problem, but gave me an instantaneous headache when I stuttered "Of course"!

Comment: @DrJay No problem at all. We all have our similar moments on this site.